# JQuery traversing the DOM

Tags: jquery

I am targeting (hiding) an element based on the click of another element.

I have successfully done this using the following...

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".AddComment").hide();
```

Is there a better way to reference the targeted node?

Using parent() this many times seems wrong when traversing the DOM.

Comment: does the `parent().parent().parent()` element has a class?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: ...or any other distinguishing feature, doesn't have to be a class.

Comment: Yes the class is .AddComment

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate post. Wouldn't know what to target search in order to find the original post